# Ideal way to disable or stub keycloak in frontend development?

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I've recently joined a team using keycloak for auth however during local frontend development a flaky keycloak container has to boot in order to do frontend. I'd like to disable to stub the keycloak-js integration, what's the recommended method for this?

Obviously there could be a conditional on NODE_ENV or similar but maybe there is a keycloak config I missed for enabling local development without running a keycloak server?

Comment: Did you ever found a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not really, I believe the team is still using keycloak in the container

Comment: Hey, i found your post afterwards. maybe this helps, if you already figured out a better solution let me know! https://stackoverflow.com/q/67193666/14721231