# Pluggable Keycloak-JS for Frontend Development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, keycloak

We are using `Keycloak` with `keycloak-js` to secure our Webapps in Production. So it is deeply integrated into our Frontends.
To start development, we always need to start a keycloak container.

Is there any good way to bypass keycloak-js and get rid of the keycloak container during dev?
The current approach is a feature toggle on `NODE_ENV`.
What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, i found a quite good solution using the `webpack.DefinePlugin`.
I define a `MYAPP_PRODUCTION` variable and replace it via Webpack in the build process.
If `MYAPP_PRODUCTION` is false override my keycloak object/export and mock the required functions.

Webpack config:
more infos: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  MYAPP_PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
  ...
}
```

Inside the app bootstrapping

```js
// sourcecode
if(!MYAPP_PRODUCTION) {
  // mock keycloak here
}
```

**the compiled output in production mode will not include the statements inside the if-clause.** webpack will automatically omit the conditional stuff because  `if (!true) { ... }` will never be true.